# Area-51 not listing all accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, linked-accounts

Over the last week or so I've noticed my Area-51 profile no longer shows all my Stack Exchange accounts, only 8 out of 21, particularly my highest-rep site (Sci-Fi & Fantasy).

Is there any explanation for this recent change in behaviour?

Comment: Same here, only 8 and can't see any pattern to the sort as well. I would tag this as a bug..

Comment: Same here, with a twist. It shows my highest rep site, then skips my next 5 sites by rep and then continues normally. Which translates to an A51 profile that, other than MSO, doesn't show any of the sites I actually participate in. Nice ;)

Comment: And they don't show beta accounts which is sad, because that site is about making beta ><!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now. The bug was introduced a couple weeks ago when we renamed some sites, and Area 51 became out of sync.